# ASP.NET page viewed in Internet Explorer 11 defaults to Document Mode: 5 (Default)?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.NET page that defaults to "Document mode: 5 (default)".  I understand that I can add a meta tag to force IE="edge" as shown below, but there's no such meta tag within this page.  Does IE set the document mode dynamically depending on the markup of the page?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge />
```

Comment: microsoft documented how IE chooses the document type [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I viewed this page previously and was not able to get an answer to my question.  Notice that the section below "The following sections explain how these rules affect how Internet Explorer selects between document modes." is blank...

Comment: it looks like that could've been due to a site redesign. the left nav shows more options. it looks like the most probably cause in your case  (imo) is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mike, it looks like the documentation you referenced is in relation to the meta tag that I outlined above.  I understand that I can set the document mode with this meta tag, but in this instance no such meta tag has been used and IE is still setting the Document mode to "IE 5 (default)".  I guess it's just one of those IE mysteries...

Comment: No, it also talks about what response headers your server is returning. Check to make sure that whatever server process hosting your site isn't returning IE=5 type response headers anywhere.

Comment: I dont see anything to indicate an IE 5 response type:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 22:02:51 GMT
Content-Length: 116814

Comment: What doctype do have you used for your content? Does it appear first on the page before any other characters or content? For example before HTML comments.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Perhaps then you could answer your own question so others can learn from you. Otherwise, can you answer the doctype question - I promise you it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the doctype explicitly resolved the issue.  I found that each individual page of this project has a different doctype declaration due to the fact that it was developed under HTLM 4.01 standards and as time progresses, developers have moved pages to HTML5 incrementally.  The page in question still contained the HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype.